# Create calculated field in Tableau with multiple strings in one column with 'ELSEIF' statement

Tags: sql, if-statement, tableau-desktop

I would like to make a calculated field in Tableau where I am able to visualize the amount of occurences of a string visualized.

I have made the following calculated field in Tableau.

```
IF [Avada Cadabra] = 1  THEN   'Avada Cadabra'  
ELSEIF [Aloha amora] = 1  THEN   'Aloha amora'  
ELSEIF [Depulso Levioso] = 1  THEN   'Depulso Levioso'  
ELSEIF [Levioso] = 1  THEN   'Levioso' 
ELSEIF [Protego] = 1  THEN   'Protego' 
ELSEIF [Avada Cadabra] = 1  THEN   'Avada Cadabra'    

END
```

However, as multiple options can be provided in the column where the data is stored, Tableau only takes the first option it encounters and sums this to the total amount of times it encountered this option, due to ELSEIF statement.

Would there also be another option to count the total amount of times that a certain string is counted in the dataframe, even if multiple string are encountered for a particular row?

Please see the following link for the workbook:

https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/tim.schouten/viz/Book1_16796557860290/Sheet1?publish=yes

I hope that my question is clear enough. If not, please let me know.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: share your work in Tableau public for better understanding, like this : https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/debayan.kar

Comment: https://public.tableau.com/app/profile/tim.schouten/viz/Book1_16796557860290/Sheet1?publish=yes